# How do I show that the complex conjugate of an integral is equal the integral of the conjugate?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f:[a,b]\mapsto \mathbb{C}$ is Riemann integrable. It is given also that $a,b \in\ $ and that $a<b $.
How do I show that:

$\int_{a}^{b} \! \overline{f(x)} \, dx=\overline{\int_{a}^{b} \! f(x) \, dx } $

$\int f(x) dx = \int \operatorname{Re} f(x) dx + i\int \operatorname{Im} f(x) dx$

$\int_{a}^{b} \! \overline{ \operatorname{Re} f(x)  + i\int \operatorname{Im} } \, dx=\overline{\int_{a}^{b} \!  \operatorname{Re} f(x) + i\int \operatorname{Im} \, dx } $

$\int_{a}^{b} \!{\operatorname{Re} f(x) dx - i\int \operatorname{Im} f(x) } \, dx={\int_{a}^{b} \! \operatorname{Re} f(x) dx - i\int \operatorname{Im} f(x) dx } $

Is that all that I need for proof?

Comment: Use the summation definition and apply the conjugation, you'll see that it converges to the conjugation of the sum

Comment: @Justin Assuming that you already have linearity, you need not go all the way back to Riemann/Darboux sums. If you don't have linearity already proven (and don't want to prove it) then that is a good approach.

Comment: Good point @hayden

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While your presentation of the proof isn't super clear, you have the right idea. A bit cleaner would be:
\begin{align}
\overline{\int_a^b{f(x) d x}} & = \overline{\int_a^b{[\mathrm{Re}f(x)+i\mathrm{Im}f(x)] dx}} \\
& = \overline{\int_a^b{\mathrm{Re}f(x) dx} + i\int_a^b{\mathrm{Im}f(x) dx}} \\
& = \int_a^b{\mathrm{Re}f(x) dx} - i\int_a^b{\mathrm{Im}f(x) dx} \\
& = \int_a^b{[ \mathrm{Re}f(x) - i\mathrm{Im}f(x)] dx} \\
& = \int_a^b{ \overline{f(x)} dx}
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, that was my idea, but you have written on better way. Thank you.