# Is the complex conjugate of an innner product the inner product of the complex conjugates

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

If we are working in a complex inner product space with elements f,g then is
$\langle f,g \rangle = \overline{\langle g,f \rangle} = \langle \overline{g},\overline{f} \rangle$ ? Obviously the first equality is true but I am wondering if the complex conjugate can be brought into the inner product.

We can assume that $\overline{f}$ is defined. In the specific problem I am working on we are in a reproducing kernel Hilbert space.

TY!

Comment: In an abstract inner product space, there is no such thing as the "conjugate" of a vector. If you pick coordinates, then you can conjugate the coordinates, but this operation *depends on what coordinates you picked*. At any rate, in that context the answer is yes.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, but as @coiso remarked you cannot make this statement generally across all inner products, but this property can be showed for certain inner products. For example, on the complex $L^2$ space of complex-valued random variables the associated inner product $\langle X, Y \rangle := \mathbb{E}[X \bar{Y}]$ satisfies the equality, using [this fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237003/how-do-i-show-that-the-complex-conjugate-of-an-integral-is-equal-the-integral-of)